# AWS RDS Snapshot Creation Time differs in dashboard and Aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

**In AWS, RDS Snapshot creation time differs.**

1. When opened my account RDS -> Snapshots -> Snapshot creation time : **Mar 31, 2016, 9:21:56 PM**
   [image]
2. From AWS CLI When ran "aws rds describe-db-snapshots" Command
   SnapshotCreateTime : **Mar 31, 2016, 9:21:56 PM**
   [image]

For the same snapshot the Time differs in different Environments.

Why is this showing different time as shown above? Please Explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashboard shows the time in your local timezone. The CLI output shows the time in UTC/GMT.

If you are in India, the time **Mar 31, 2016, 9:21:56 PM / IST** is same as **Mar 31, 2016, 15:51:56 PM / GMT**

```
Mar 31, 2016, 9:21:56 PM (IST) = Mar 31, 2016, 15:51:56 PM (GMT)
```

In short, same time is displayed in different timezone.